# XMLHttpRequest readyState == 3 in Opera

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, opera

My app provides clients with an immediate partial response instead of making them wait for the whole response to complete.

All the major browsers handle the partial response correctly, except Opera.

Here's what's happening:

Breakpoints have been set up on each line of code that handles the partial response (a.k.a. readyState 3), like it's shown below:

```
if (this.readyState == 3) {
  $(".serverResponse").html(xhr.responseText); // Breakpoint set up here
}
```

Every major browser grabs the chunks, one by one, and fills them in inside xhr.responseText (also on xhr.response, but that's outside the question) on every execution of xhr.onreadystatechange, so that the client can gradually see the response's progress on an arbitrary element, for which I've given a class of serverResponse. So serverResponse grows like this:

```
response1
response1 response2
response1 response2 response3
etc...
```

Now, what does Opera do?

Opera grabs the WHOLE response on the FIRST run of xhr.onreadystatechange. After the first run, serverResponse is already like this:

```
response1 response2 response3
```

It's like Opera doesn't wait for any partial response, or simply doesn't even care for any responses at all. It just seems to run the xhr functions for no reason.

Why this?

Because if I remove the breakpoints, serverResponse will not get any response written on it. HOWEVER, if I add the breakpoint and not let the script run for a few seconds, there it is, the whole response is written on serverResponse.

This all just seems to be some kind of bizarre behaviour from Opera, which I suspect to be a caching issue.

Is there any way to make Opera behave like the other browsers?

EDIT: To make things clearer, Opera still grabs the response gradually, but it does NOT seem to inform xhr.onreadystatechange of that change. All the major browsers grab the first thing they see and just stop at the breakpoint, waiting for the next chunk as soon as I let the script continue to run.

They also run the xhr.onreadystatechange function multiple times (the major browsers seem to make this function run in a loop as soon as there is a new chunk available from the server) until the server ends the response. Opera only runs the function ONCE and it doesn't seem like it wants to wait for ANY response at all, which explains why serverResponse only gets text written on it if I let the breakpoint activated for a few seconds before I let the script run again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't like to answer my own questions, but here it goes anyway...

The issue arose because I was using an older version of Opera (12.17 to be precise). I got Opera 22 and it can now handle partial responses just like the other major browsers. A cherry on top now would be to check the change logs to see when they fixed this particular issue, but I'm not bothering with that.

Up-to-date browsers solve so many problems. Keep your browsers updated!